# cakephp paginate with associated model

Tags: cakephp, pagination

User has many User_Questionaries. I want paginate users that have particular questionnaire. I used following pagination for it.

```
$paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.role' => IWOA,
        'UserQuestionary.questionary_id' => $id
    ),
    'recursive' => 1,
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => array(
        'name' => 'asc'
    ),
    'contain' => array('UserQuestionary')
);
```

But it is not create join query. It is showing  `Unknown column UserQuestionary.questionary_id' in 'where clause'`

What is the issue? How can i do it?

Comment: 'contain' is not 'join', have you check the [join section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) of the docs?

Comment: Have you setup the joins in the models? Paginate is used in controllers so if the model for that controller doesn't have the join it wont work.

I also think your User.role should have quotes around it as you asking it to look for a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used join query for do this.

```
$paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Iwoa.role' => IWOA,                
            ),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'alias' => 'UserQuestionary',
                    'table' => 'user_questionaries',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => 'UserQuestionary.user_id = Iwoa.id AND UserQuestionary.questionary_id = ' . $id
                )
            ),
            'limit' => 10,
            'order' => array(
                'name' => 'asc'
            ),
        );
```